# JMeter fails to simulate browser response time

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm trying to simulate a connection to a website. The goal of the simulation is to collect statistics on page loading time on browser side.

I configured JMeter Flagging the option Retrieve Embedded Resources in order to simulate the real time to load the whole page. The issue is that while from a real Browser i have a response time (let's assume for the page A the response time is 10 seconds) in JMeter I found i response time 20 times higher.

It seems JMeter takes a much longer time to gather embedded resources (e.g. js, images, ...)

Do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Kind Regards

---

Update 31/07

I discovered some resources are not completely downloaded. Using Firebug i see some components with 0 bytes downloaded that the browsere keep trying to download (but the user do not percieve since the page is loaded). Therefore i suspect JMeter keeps trying downloading it. Is there any chance to set a timeout to overcome this kind of situation?

---

Update_1 31/07
I figured out that the issue is related with nested iframes. setting httpsampler.max_frame_depth=0 i get the correct time. however i would like to understand the reason of this issue. Do I have to set other paramters?

Answer (score 0):

Disable browser cache and re-run your test in browser.

Jmeter will not store cache, unless otherwise specified.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan.

Real browsers retrieve images, scripts, styles, etc. but do it **only once**. In order to simulate browser behavior you need to configure JMeter appropriately.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more test elements which can be used for this.

Comment: I added as suggested the cached manager. However i do testing in the following way: 1) I clear browser cache and i gather the timing to load the page 2)i try the same with JMeter. The time of response is quite different. I think is not matter of caching since i delete it before doing the tests

Comment: In the guide mentioned there is a hint for using concurrent pool for retrieving embedded resources. Have you applied it? If you don't need any performance testing and measuring page load time can be done in one thread it makes sense to consider JMeter WebDriver Sampler or Selenium WebDriver without JMeter.

Comment: I set "4" for concurrent pool retrieving. We actually would like to stress the system  calculating the response time percieved by the user in condition of a huge number of concurrent user. We first try with one single thread in order to understand if the configuration is correct